# Python CSV reader doesnt have any data

Tags: python, list, csv

The following code work fine.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        cur.execute(insertStatement, row)
```

when I insert these two lines, something goes wrong.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    totalrows = len(list(reader))
    print totalrows # Print out the correct output
    for row in reader:
        cur.execute(insertStatement, row)
```

My guess is that when i assign totalrows = len(list(reader))
the cursor moves to the end of the file there for nothing happens in the for loop.

if this is true how can i move the cursor back to the start without closing the file and reopening it? if not please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right, the file has been consumed and subsequent reads on `reader` will not return data.

You can get around this by calling `f.seek(0)` on the underlying file, i.e.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    totalrows = len(list(reader))
    print totalrows # Print out the correct output
    f.seek(0)
    for row in reader:
        cur.execute(insertStatement, row)
```

Comment: @M.ofCA : Blair makes an important point about not reading the file twice in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24320195/21945)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reading it once, creating and throwing away a list, and reading it again, why don't you keep the list and iterate over that?

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    allrows = list(reader)
    totalrows = len(allrows)
    print totalrows # Print out the correct output
    for row in allrows:
        cur.execute(insertStatement, row)
```

Also, many database libraries allow you to insert multiple records at once which is often quicker than inserting them one at a time. Check the documentation for whatever database library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If that is whats happening, try using `f.seek(0)` that puts the cursor back to the beginning.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
totalrows = len(list(reader))
print totalrows # Print out the correct output
f.seek(0)  # Moves pointer back to beginning of file
for row in reader:
    cur.execute(insertStatement, row)
```